# click button twice to call ajax to load modal window

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

It is taking two clicks to work:

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".submit").click(function(){ editor.post(); }); // for post on TinyMCE

$('#modal').modal({ show: false });
});

$("#reviewbutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form = $('#update');
    editor.post();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update-preview.php",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: form.serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#modal .modal-body').html(data);
            $('#modal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

Here is the modal window code (hidden on page load):

```
<style> #modal .modal-dialog { width: 80%; } </style>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Preview of your job at Job Hunter</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form is as follows:

```
 <form action="/UpdateListing/<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" name="update" id="update">
```

More form elements here...

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button class='btn btn-primary submit' type='submit' id='reviewbutton' name='reviewbutton'>REVIEW</button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="jid" value="<?php echo $jid; ?>">
                    <button class='btn btn-green submit' type='submit' id='updatebutton' name='updatebutton'>SAVE UPDATES</button>
                   </div>
```

The review button is supposed to call the ajax to send form data to the page and then load this in the modal window.

THe program is that I have to click the button 'reviewbutton' twice and after the second click the window opens but a copy of the html page loads into the window.

My code works on another page and the only difference is the the form action is to a simple url e.g. action-"/someurl" rather than on this page which is action = "/someurl/id".  This is why I am using the hidden field as the second button submits the form 'updatebutton' for validation etc.

I cannot figure out what the issue is?

Comment: the review button click listener should be inside `document.ready` like the other ones are

Comment: Tried this and it makes no difference

Comment: any errors thrown? is page reloading on first click by chance? Does button exist on page load?

Comment: When button is first clicked Firebug shows me that the call to ajax was successful.  I can see the post data which looks ok but the html being returned (console data) is the complete calling page and not the preview code I have in the ajax php page.  When I click the button a second time the modal window appears but with a complete copy of the calling html page.  I suspect it's something on the first button click?

Comment: so which url is it going to on first click? something strange happening there it sounds like

Comment: and what does `editor.post();` code do?

Comment: update-preview.php in the ajax url parameter.  This page should return a basic page that shows the layout of what the form data will look like when listed on the website.  It is weird as it is returning the complete calling/parent html page back.

Comment: I use an editor on a textarea and this is required in order to post the data from the editor on form submission.  I commented out this line as a test and it makes not difference .  I still need to click the button twice.